# Error al instalar bcrypt usando bundle install

Tags: ruby, rubygems

estaba instalando las gems con las que opera Metasploit, y en la librería bcrypt me salió este error:

```
Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ruby -I
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190627-18317-12zh00w.rb
extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
arm-linux-androideabi-clang  -D__SKIP_GNU -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include
-c -o x86.o x86.S
x86.S:202:29: error: expected '%<type>' or "<type>"
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
                            ^
make: *** [<builtin>: x86.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13 for inspection.
Results logged to
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.6.0/bcrypt-3.1.13/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.13), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.13' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  metasploit-framework was resolved to 5.0.33, which depends on
    bcrypt
```

Ya intenté con `gem install bcrypt -v 3.1.13` e instalando ruby-dev, rvm, json, build-essential,  pero nada. Ya han hecho esta misma pregunta, pero las respuestas no son mi solución. Gracias por responder. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error al parecer se produce en la última versión, la cual agregó [este PR](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/pull/184) (que es donde se genera el error que muestras `x86.S:202:29: error: expected '%<type>' or "<type>"`). De hecho al parecer no es [el primer error](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/201) que se reporta para este cambio en sistemas ARM.
Yo creo que podrías probar instalando la versión anterior:

```
gem install bcrypt -v 3.1.12
```

Respecto a metasploit, podrías modificar el [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/fcd77b1314d60e22da25c49558c8ade91acebba1/Gemfile.lock#L140) para que use la versión anterior. Creo que no debería dar mayores problemas, ya que sería un patch downgrade.

Si quieres aportar tu grano de arena, creo que sería buena idea que reportaras el error en el/los repositorio(s) del proyecto. Saludos